# Unable to ping from the SQL server in Azure

Tags: sql, azure

I have 3 VMs in Azure, one of them is DC and DNS, the other one is going to be SCCM, the ther one is SQL server.

I joined the two VMs to my DC. They have correct IP config. One of them is just fine. I can ping DC from the SSCM and vice versa.

But from the SQL server I cannot ping. `nslookup` does not work correctly either, but the IP config is correct.

Does any one know where is the problem?

Note: DNS server is fine. Also, I have records in DNS server that are pointing to SCCM and SQL.

Comment: Can you clarify which way the ping is not working?  For example, is it DC -> SQL or SQL -> DC that is not working.  Or both?

Comment: it does not work both ways

Comment: I created another VM with windows 2012

Comment: Ping worked , DNS fine, then again, installed SQL server 2012, ping worked, dns fine. restarted the VM nslookup does not work anymore, ping does not work any more. So it should be some setting about SQL server taht I am missing, Oh and Firewalls are off on all VMs

Answer (score 1):

Ping is disabled by default on the Windows Server VM's.  Sign-in to the VM you want to ping and open the Server Manager (icon in the lower left corner).

In the upper right corner where the menu is, select **Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**.  Click on the **Inbound Rules** in the left navigation, locate the **File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)** rule.  Right-click on it to enable it.

[image]

Now you should be able to ping it from other VM's in your Virtual Network.

Comment: Is ping not even resolving your VM name to an IP Address?

Comment: no I get one time out and one destination host unreachable

Comment: I mean you get four replays by default thery are one by one differetn

Comment: In your virtual network where these VM's are deployed, did you add your DC/DNS server (10.0.0.4) to the dns servers section of the configure page for your virtual network?